# Error processing packages when trying to install python-pygame

Tags: apt, elementary

Whatever I try to install using apt-get install , it simply doesn't work.

I've been using Elementary OS (based on Ubuntu) since yesterday, so I'm pretty new to Linux.

Here's an example of my problem:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-pygame is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apport kde-l10n-engb python-urllib3
Suggested packages:
  apport-gtk apport-kde
Recommended packages:
  apport-symptoms
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport kde-l10n-engb python-urllib3
3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
19 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.537 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9.875 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 209029 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10_all.deb ...
apport stop/waiting
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 14: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: 13: /var/lib/dpkg/info/apport.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Preparing to unpack .../kde-l10n-engb_4%3a4.13.0-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking kde-l10n-engb (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) over (4:4.13.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python-urllib3_1.7.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-urllib3.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-urllib3.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-urllib3_1.7.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-urllib3.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-urllib3.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.10_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-urllib3_1.7.1-1ubuntu3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try running `sudo apt-get update` first.  Sometimes other updates need to be applied before new things are installed.

Comment: Tried this a few times - doesn't change anything. But as it gives an error too, that could be the problem: "E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead." Possibly the old ones won't work?

Comment: Did you try to install it with aptitud?
First install aptitude with this:
sudo apt-get install aptitude
then :
sudo aptitude install <name-of-package>

Comment: did you run `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. For some reason you cannot install the pygame package directly using `apt-get`. I suggest you to go to pygame's website [download section](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) and download `pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz` (or whatever is the stable release).

open your terminal and navigate to the downloaded folder. Unzip the file, assuming you are in the `Downloads` Directory

```
tar -xvf pygame-1.9.1release.tar.gz
cd pygame-1.9.1release   #navigate to the extracted directory
```

and run the following command in order to install the package.

```
sudo python Setup.py
```

This should install the pygame package for you.

Alternatively you can download the stable release of pygame from [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/python-pygame/download) for AMD architecture and [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/python-pygame/download) for i386 as a deb package and install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped!